What properties must be verified for a simple OLS regression model with time series?
Let's say I have 3 time series variables, $(X_t)$, $(Y_{t})$, $(Z_{t})$ and I estimate the following model with OLS estimator (I believe this form is called ARDL) :
$$X_{t} \quad = \quad \alpha_1 X_{t-1} \quad + \quad \alpha_2 Y_{t}  \quad + \quad \alpha_3 Z_{t-1}  \quad + \alpha_4Z_{t-2}  \quad + \quad \varepsilon_t$$
where $\varepsilon_t$ is the error term.
What properties should be verified for this regression to hold ?
Here is what I thought should be checked :

$(X_t)$, $(Y_{t})$ and $(Z_{t})$ are stationary time series
no multicolinearity between $(X_t)$, $(Y_{t})$ and $(Z_{t})$ i.e. correlations between variables are sufficiently weak.
the error $\varepsilon_t$ is homoskedastic : $var(\varepsilon_t) = \sigma$ where $\sigma$ does not depend on $t$
the error $\varepsilon_t$ has no autocorrelation : $cov(\varepsilon_t,\varepsilon_{t-k})=0 \quad \forall   (t,k) \in \Bbb{N}^2 $
the error $\varepsilon_t$ is centered : $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t) = 0 $
the error $\varepsilon_t$ is stationary (but is that not already implied by what's above ?)
the error $\varepsilon_t$ is normaly distributed (optional)
the AR(1) and AR(2) processes of $(X_t)$ and $(Z_t)$ have coefficients smaller than 1 in absolute value in order to be stationary :

$ |\alpha_1| \in \left]0;1\right[ $
$ |\alpha_3| \in \left]0;1\right[ $
$ |\alpha_4| \in \left]0;1\right[ $



Is there something I missed ?
Thanks a lot !

What properties should be verified for this regression to hold ? What do you mean that the regression will "hold"? Nothing stops you from sending the numbers through the regression machinery. Do you want certain properties for confidnce intervals or hypothesis tests? Do you want unbiased or consistent coefficient estimates? Do you want the estimator to have the minumum variance among unbiased linear estimators like you would get from the Gauss-Markov theorem?

OLS really doesn't care whether the series are stationary or about the degree of multicollinearity among the explanatory variables: whether that's an issue depends on what you are expecting and what you hope to achieve.  The other criteria are covered well in other threads here such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32600 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16381 (but beware the lower-voted answers there...).

@Dave, Thanks ! Well yes, my first best would be a BLUE estimator like we would get from Gauss-Markov theorem. If that's not possible here, an unbiased estimator will do. But my main doubt initially was rather : is there a risk that my regression is fallacious ? For instance, if you regress $X_t$ on $Y_t$ with $X_t$, $Y_t$ being integrated time series, the regression will "not hold" in the sense it will be fallacious and Student tests can not be interpreted. But a cointegration between $X_t$ and $Y_t$ can sort the problem out, so here cointegration is what would make the regression "hold".

Hello @whuber. I have read the links you've given, but they don't make a case for the specific context of time series. To be honest, I'm astonished by the answers here. Clearly if $(X_t)$, $(Y_t)$ and $(Z_t)$ are I(1) and at the same time the series are not cointegrated, the regression will be fallacious. In these conditions, I don't understand how "OLS doesn't care about stationarity" ? It seems that OLS does care, and cointegration exists because of that. At the very least, I would have expected an answer like "Beware, all your series should be stationary".

Well, it seems my surprises find an answer here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94727/308815  In a few words : "To obtain useful results you can't use nonstationary data with OLS and time series, except in case of cointegrated series. There are other more advanced methods where nonstationarity is a non issue." It does not mention the complete list of hypothesis to validate for having the best properties, but from the answers of @Dave and @ whuber, I can infer that it's akin to regression for cross-sections data, i.e. if I want to have a BLUE I just have to rely on Gauss-Markov theorem.

I am not sure there is any feasible BLUE for an ARDL model, and OLS is certainly not it. The trouble is with the bias of most of the usual estimators, including OLS.

It seems that there is already an answer on Cross-Validated that answers (partially) my question: Using non-stationary time series data in OLS regression.

To obtain useful results you can't use nonstationary data with OLS and time series, except in case of cointegrated series. There are other more advanced methods where nonstationarity is a non issue.

This does not mention the complete list of hypothesis that we would preferably check for such a regression.
But from answers by @Dave and @whuber I can infer that I'm free to validate or not the assumptions of Gauss-Markov theorem, and if doing so I can expect a BLUE just like for cross-section analysis.
However, from the responses given by Dave and whuber, it seems that the perspective underlying my question was wrong. I was under the impression that time series are a strange beast, in which assumptions for a valid regression were very special. This assumption seems generaly wrong, and time series regression should be considered very akin to cross-section regressions, except for the well-known case of time-series with integration order $I(1)$ or larger, which yield "spurious regression" unless those series are cointegrated.
@Dave and @whuber, thank you for your answers!

I am not sure there is any feasible BLUE for an ARDL model, and OLS is certainly not it. The trouble is with the bias of most of the usual estimators, including OLS.

Hello Richard, thanks for your answer. Your remark implies there would be more to time-series models (at least a particular model like ARDL) than just applying the same assumptions as for cross-section case. Which was precisely why I raised the question in the first place. If most usual estimators are, as you say, biased with ARDL, then what estimator should be chosen in order to get the "best case scenario" (not necessarly unbiased, but asymptoticaly unbiased) ?

Generally speaking (so not specific to ARDL), maximum likelihood estimators are often the "best" asymptotically. I do not remember enough theory to specify exactly what "best" means, but it may be something about being consistent and then also having the smallest variance matrix among the class of consistent estimators (asymptotic Cramer-Rao lower bound?). Bayesian estimators may be optimal in their own sense, but they may be more tedious to implement and take longer to compute.

@Richard thanks for the indications ! I will look further in this direction.
